# Pass Array of objects From Java to PLSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I am trying to pass Java array object to PLSQL stored procedure, however when I am trying to execute, I am getting the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types
```

My Dao Class:

```
public class UploadTradeDaoImpl implements UploadTradeDao{

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(UploadTradeDaoImpl.class);
private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

public SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    return sqlSessionFactory;
}

public void setSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
    this.sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactory;
}

public int uploadTrade(List<UploadTrade> uploadTradeList) {

    SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        Connection conn = session.getConnection().getMetaData()
                .getConnection();
        StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor
                .createDescriptor("UPLOADTRADE_OBJ", conn);
        STRUCT[] testStruct= new STRUCT[uploadTradeList.size()];
        ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor= ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
                "UPLOADTRADE_REC", conn);
        Object[] upload_obj_array = new Object[uploadTradeList.size()];
        for (int index = 0; index < uploadTradeList.size(); index++) {
            UploadTrade uploadTradeObj = uploadTradeList.get(index);
            Object[] uploadObjects = new Object[] {
                    uploadTradeObj.getBusTrdId(),
                    uploadTradeObj.getIntrnlExtl(),
                    uploadTradeObj.getMarsLe(),
                    uploadTradeObj.getLeg1CflwType(),
                     uploadTradeObj.getLeg2CflwType(),
                    uploadTradeObj.getRestmntCode(),
                    uploadTradeObj.getRestmntQtr(),
                    uploadTradeObj.getTrdId()};
            upload_obj_array[index] = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, conn, uploadObjects);

        }
        ARRAY obj_array = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, upload_obj_array);

        CallableStatement callableStatement= conn.prepareCall("call INSERTUPLOADTRADEOBJ(?,?)");
        callableStatement.setArray(1, obj_array);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"UPLOADTRADE_REC");
        callableStatement.execute();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.rollback();
        log.error("Error! in UploadTrade()" + e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    } finally {

        session.close();

    }
    return 1;

}
```

I am doing this using these 2 links:
https://community.oracle.com/message/4329339#4329339

[Pass array from Java to Oracle: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888520/pass-array-from-java-to-oracle-java-sql-sqlexception-fail-to-convert-to-intern)

please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try out [OracleCallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) and `setObject()` instead of `setArray()`

Comment: Hi OracleUser Thanks for suggestion but I tried it with setObject() also but now working is there any possibilities that the procedure may have error.

Comment: in which line you get the error exactly? in execute?

Comment: upload_obj_array[index] = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, conn, uploadObjects); in this line

Comment: What is the definition of the type `UPLOADTRADE_OBJ`? It appears that oracle is complaining that your arguments in your Object[] do not match the type Oracle is expecting.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the Support I an able to get it but now I am in new trouble every thing is working fine but data not inserting in database

Answer (score 2):

## Example

```
userEntitlementDescriptor =  ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TWO_D_TYPE", conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class));
    userDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_ARRAY", conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class));  
    userListArray = new ARRAY(userDescriptor, conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class), userArray);  

    call = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call USER_ENTITLEMENT_CHECK(?,?,?) }");
    call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "TWO_D_TYPE"); // or whatever it is
    call.setString(2, entitlementTags);
    call.setString(3, contentId);
    call.setArray(4, userListArray);
    call.execute();
    userEntitlementArray = (ARRAY) call.getObject(1);
    ResultSet rsl = userEntitlementArray.getResultSet();
    while(rsl.next()){
      ARRAY varray3 = (ARRAY) rsl.getObject (2);
      String[] entitlementResultArray = (String[])varray3.getArray();
      userEntitlementMap.put(entitlementResultArray[0], entitlementResultArray[1]);
    }

}
catch(SQLException sqlException){
    SERVICE_LOGGER.error("Error while making silverpop call for content id--"+contentId);
}
```

## Glossary

- TWO_D_TYPE -- array type in Oracle,
- T_ARRAY   -- array type in Oracle,
- userArray -- array in java,
- entitlementTags,contentId -- string object in java,
- conn -- connection object in java,
- call -- callable statement