# java array blob data insert to oracle db using by stored procudure(Fail to convert to internal representation:error)

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, blob

I want to array BLOB data save to Oracle DB using by stored procedure.
(reference from this : [Pass array from Java to Oracle: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888520/pass-array-from-java-to-oracle-java-sql-sqlexception-fail-to-convert-to-intern))

But I have added BLOB column to struct.
Here is my db script and java code.

**--DB code--**
    CREATE TABLE project_types (
    proj_id VARCHAR2(10),
    proj_title VARCHAR2(10),
    proj_data BLOB
    );
    /

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE project_type AS OBJECT ( 
proj_id VARCHAR2(10),
proj_title VARCHAR2(10),
proj_data BLOB
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_array AS TABLE OF project_type;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_projects(p_projects_array IN my_array)
AS
BEGIN
IF p_projects_array IS NOT NULL THEN
FOR v_i IN 1..p_projects_array.LAST
LOOP
INSERT INTO project_types
VALUES (p_projects_array(v_i).proj_id,
p_projects_array(v_i).proj_title,
p_projects_array(v_i).proj_data);
END LOOP;
END IF;
END;
/
```

I have added BLOB data column to project_types table and project_type TYPE,
SturedProcedure.

```
--Table--
proj_data BLOB

-- TYPE--
proj_data BLOB

--StruedProcedure--
p_projects_array(v_i).proj_data
```

**-- Java code --**

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Struct;

import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection;

public class calMilisecond {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
String user = "testuser";
String password = "testuser123456";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);;

OracleCallableStatement callStmt = null;
try {
  callStmt = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("{call add_projects(?)}");

  Blob blob1 = new SerialBlob(("test1").getBytes());
  Blob blob2 = new SerialBlob(("test2").getBytes());
  // create array holding values for ProjectType object's properties
  Object[] project1 = new Object[] {"1", "Title 1", blob1};
  Object[] project2 = new Object[] {"2", "Title 2", null};

  // each struct is one ProjectType object
  Struct structProject1 = conn.createStruct("PROJECT_TYPE", project1);
  Struct structProject2 = conn.createStruct("PROJECT_TYPE", project2);

  Struct[] structArrayOfProjects = {structProject1, structProject2};

  // array holding two ProjectType objects
  Array arrayOfProjects = ((OracleConnection) conn).createOracleArray("MY_ARRAY", structArrayOfProjects);

  callStmt.setArray(1, arrayOfProjects); 
  callStmt.execute();
  //conn.commit();

  System.out.println("Committed.");
} catch (Exception e) {
  if (conn != null) try { conn.rollback(); } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("Rollback failed."); }
  throw e;
} finally {
  callStmt.close();
  conn.close();
 }    

}
```

**-- Error Code --**

**//Error occur when I try to insert blobs data to DB. //**

Object[] project1 = new Object[] {"1", "Title 1", blob1};

Object[] project2 = new Object[] {"2", "Title 2", blob2};

> > java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal
> >     representation:error    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeBLOB.toDatum(OracleTypeBLOB.java:69) at
> >     oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleType.toDatumInternal(OracleType.java:142) at
> >     oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toOracleArray(StructDescriptor.java:741)
> >     at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toArray(StructDescriptor.java:1322) at
> >     oracle.sql.STRUCT.(STRUCT.java:136) at
> >     oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStruct(PhysicalConnection.java:8733)

**-- No error when I try to use NULL data --**

Object[] project1 = new Object[] {"1", "Title 1", null};

Object[] project2 = new Object[] {"2", "Title 2", null};

> Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Blob blob1 = new SerialBlob(("test1").getBytes());
```

to

```
  BLOB blob1 =  new BLOB((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)conn, ("test1").getBytes());
```

where `BLOB` is `import oracle.sql.BLOB;`

And the rest of your code should be OK.

Comment: This method is deprecated. Please [look at this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/BLOB.html). You must use `import java.sql.Blob;` instead of `import oracle.sql.BLOB;`

Comment: Yes, it's true, for oracle 12c driver.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post an answer because I was struggling with this for a while. I had a method in place that worked that was similar to @Arkadiusz answer, but it is deprecated.

I am not sure why you are getting your that error, but maybe try this method.

```
import java.sql.Blob; 
...

public class MyClassDAO {   
    public static int sendBlobToDb(MyObject myObject) {
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;     
        OutputStream os = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oop = null;
        Blob blob = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        index = 0;
        int result = 0;

        String sql = "begin "
             + "insert into myTable "
             + "(ITEMID, SOME_TEXT, SOME_NUMBER, THE_BLOB_FIELD) values "
             + "(ITEMID_SEQ.nextval, ?, ?, empty_blob()) "
             + "return THE_BLOB_FIELD into ?; "
             + "end; ";

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

            cstmt.setString(++index, myObject.getSomeText());
            cstmt.setLong(++index, myObject.getSomeNumber());
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(++index, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
            cstmt.executeUpdate();

            blob = (Blob) cstmt.getBlob(index);
            os = blob.setBinaryStream(1L);
            oop = new ObjectOutputStream(os); 
            oop.writeObject(myObject.getListData());
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            result = -1;
            //log exception
            try {
                if(conn != null) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            } catch(SQLException se2) {
                //log exception
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            result = -1;
            //log exception
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
                if (oop != null) {
                    oop.flush();
                    oop.close();
                }
                if (os != null) {
                    os.close();
                }
                if (cstmt != null) {
                    cstmt.close();
                }
            } catch(SQLException se) {
                result = -1;
                //log exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = -1;
                //log exception
            }
        }

    return result;
    }
}
```

I would send an object to a blob field in Oracle using something like this. I have not tested this yet so hopefully it works.